# How to set ariaLabel for toast and Messagebox

Tags: javascript, extjs, accessibility, wai-aria, extjs6-classic

I have a Ext.toast and Ext.Msg to be displayed on button click. So on click of button the content of toast and messagebox should be read.

I have applied ariaLabel but its still not readable, tried setting `focus` and `containsFocus` as well but still no luck, when I set `defaultFocus:1` on messagebox it works for the first time only. Any hints please.

```
 Ext.toast({
     html: 'Data Saved',
     title: 'My Title',
     width: 200,
     align: 't',
     ariaLabel: 'My Title Data Saved'
 });

Ext.Msg.show({
     title: 'Invalid search criteria',
     msg: 'check',
     ariaLabel:'Invalid search criteria check',
     icon: Ext.Msg.ERROR,
     buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
});
```

Screen reader to be used - NVDA

Fiddle can be found [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/36jf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that attribute `aria-labelledby` is always set automatically. (and has the higher precedence [ariaLabelledBy](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-ariaLabelledBy)). I did not find a way to avoid automatic substitution, so I created an override that does this for window instances

```
Ext.define('Ext.window.WindowAriaOverride', {
    override: 'Ext.window.Window',
    afterShow: function () {
        this.el.dom.setAttribute('aria-labelledby', null)

        this.el.dom.setAttribute('aria-label', this.ariaLabel)
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/36nd)

Comment: putting ariaRole along with containsFocus did the job, override not required. thanks for the trick..

Answer (score 1):

If you will look at the documentation of the Ext.Msg.show, you will not find there any aria* config/param. This config is available only to Ext.window.MessageBox class.
I have changed your fiddle example to force it work, but unfortunately this aria features looks like to be buggy.

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Fiddle',

launch: function () {

    Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'toast',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        handler: function () {
            Ext.create('Ext.window.Toast', {
                html: 'Data Saved',
                title: 'My Title',
                width: 200,
                align: 't',
                containsFocus: true,
                closeAction: 'destroy',
                ariaLabel: 'ARIA_LABEL_VALUE',
                //ariaLabelledBy: 'ARIA_LABELLED_BY',
                ariaDescribedBy: "ARIA_DESCRIBED_BY",
                listeners: {
                    show: function () {
                        console.log(
                            this.el.dom.getAttribute('aria-label'),
                            this.el.dom.getAttribute('aria-labelledby'),
                            this.el.dom.getAttribute('aria-describedby')
                        );
                    }
                }
            }).show();

        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'msgbox',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        handler: function () {
            Ext.create('Ext.window.MessageBox', {
                closeAction: 'destroy',
                ariaLabel: 'ARIA_LABEL_VALUE',
                //ariaLabelledBy: 'ARIA_LABELLED_BY',
                ariaDescribedBy: "ARIA_DESCRIBED_BY",
                listeners: {
                    show: function () {
                        console.log(
                            this.el.dom.getAttribute('aria-label'),
                            this.el.dom.getAttribute('aria-labelledby'),
                            this.el.dom.getAttribute('aria-describedby')
                        );
                    }
                }
            }).show({
                title: 'Invalid search criteria',
                cls: 'error-message',
                msg: 'yooo',
                containsFocus: true,
                ariaLabel: 'msg yoo',
                modal: true,
                icon: Ext.Msg.ERROR,
                buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,

            });
        }
    });
}
});
```

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/36kb)